# Is there a bug in this python module or am I using it the wrong way?

Tags: python, python-requests, bigcommerce

lambda from getattr getting called with "connection" as a keyword argument? Am I misusing the code or is there a bug?

Code and traceback: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python/issues/32

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import bigcommerce
import bigcommerce.api

BIG_URL = 'store-45eg5.mybigcommerce.com'
BIG_USER = 'henry'
BIG_KEY = '10f0f4f371f7953c4d7d7809b62463281f15c829'

api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host=BIG_URL, basic_auth=(BIG_USER, BIG_KEY))
def get_category_id(name):
    get_request = api.Categories.get(name)
    try:
        cat_list = api.Categories.all(name=name)
            if cat_list:
                return cat_list[0]['id']
            else:
                return None
            except:
                return None
def create_category(name):
    rp = api.Categories.create(name)
    if rp.status == 201:
        return rp.json()['id']
    else:
        return get_category_id(name)
create_category('anothertestingcat')
```

Gives this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./bigcommerceimporter.py", line 50, in 
create_category('anothertestingcat')
File "./bigcommerceimporter.py", line 44, in create_category
rp = api.Categories.create(name)
File "/home/henry/big_test_zone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigcommerce/api.py", line 57, in 
return lambda args, *kwargs: (getattr(self.resource_class, item))(args, connection=self.connection, *kwargs)
TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'connection'
```

Line in api.py that the traceback refers to: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python/blob/master/bigcommerce/api.py#L57

Comment: Instead of linking to an external snippet, please include a self-contained example demonstrating the problem in the body of your post.

Comment: You're using it the wrong way probably

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/ebe9be3ea7ce code

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/25b11c38c14e traceback

Comment: @user2970983 **in the body of your post**. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Is that a little better? Sorry, first time asking a question on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, this is a good question now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [examples](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python), create should be used like this:

```
api.Categories.create(name = 'anothertestingcat')
```

*Note: You should generate a new API KEY, since you published the current one in this question.*